# Attempting to send array through GET method, but unable to unserialize

Tags: php

```
$subprompt = serialize($errors);
            header('Location: landingpage.php?success=false&prompt=' . $prompt . '&subprompt=' . $subprompt);
```

then

```
if(isset($_GET['subprompt'])){

    $subprompt = $_GET['subprompt'];

    $subprompt = unserialize($subprompt);
print_r($subprompt);
}
```

I get all the data when I echo just the $_GET variable, however when I try to unserialize it I get nothing; a blank variable.

Comment: Don't go overboard with adding things like this - most browsers  have length limits on URLs (including the query string). A couple hundred chars is ok, but don't expect a very large array to come through intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Besides urlencode, you can try base64 encoding the data. A bit "prettier" url :)

```
$subprompt = base64_encode(serialize($errors));
            header('Location: landingpage.php?success=false&prompt=' . $prompt . '&subprompt=' . $subprompt);
```

And

```
if(isset($_GET['subprompt'])){
    $subprompt = $_GET['subprompt'];
    $subprompt = unserialize(base64_decode($subprompt));
print_r($subprompt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$subprompt = urlencode(serialize($errors));
```

Answer (score 1):

urlencode is intended for this purpose.

```
$url_string = urlencode(serialize($errors));
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid encoding issues, you should send the value as `base64_encode(serialize($subprompt));` instead. The result will be about a 33% longer string, so keep in mind to not exceed the maximum url length.